# Jquery: keyup-input does not detect change from datepicker

Tags: jquery, dictionary, input, datepicker

i want to code a live-search (mysql) with jquery. there are four search parameters (lastname, forename, startdate, enddate), which should perform a live-search (AND) based on the input in all boxes. the dates are selected with the datepicker widget.

while my code works fine with fore- and lastname, added and changed dates are not recognized by the .keyUp() on the input fields (but are displayed in the input fields).

how can i get the dates working without breaking the names ?

the script (placed at the end of the document):

```
 -- plain html stripped --
 lastname <input id="lastname" type="text" name="lastname" />
 <br />
 forename <input id="forename" type="text" name="forename" />
 <br />
 startdate <input id="startdate" type="text" name="startdate" />
 <br />
 enddate <input id="enddate" type="text" name="enddate" />    

<script>
$(function() {
      var dateOptions = {
            showMonthAfterYear: false,
            showOn: 'both',
            yearRange: "-40:+10",
            changeYear: true,
            changeMonth: true,
        };  
$( "#startdate" ).datepicker(dateOptions);
$( "#enddate" ).datepicker(dateOptions);
});
</script>
<script>
$('input').keyup(function () {
var inputData = [];
$('input').map(function () {
    inputData.push({"name" : this.name, "value" : this.value});
}).get();

$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST",
    url: "dbquery.php",             
    data: inputData,
    dataType: "html", 
    success: function(response){                    
        $("#responsecontainer").html(response); 
        return response;
    }});
});
```

Comment: Try `$('input[name$="date"]').change(.....`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A key-up event wont be triggered on the datePicker because you don't use a keyboard to interact with it. Listen for the `change` event instead (/as well):

Replace: 
`$('input').keyup(function () {...`

With `$(':input').on("keyup change", function () {...`

Comment: Is that  `:input` a typo?

Comment: Nope. `:input` means *any* input including textareas and selects. https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/. It may or may not be appropriate here but can't hurt.

Comment: i just noticed that the ajax query is done twice: the first time when a letter is entered in one of the textboxes, but a second time, when clicking with the mouse everywhere else, which seems related to the "change".

how do i fix that ?

Comment: @mmrks6 - It's fired when the key is pressed AND when the field is 'changed'. For a text field the change event isn't triggered until the field looses focus (ie: you click elsewhere). There are several solutions: 1. Remove the keyup event listener and just use on-change for all fields. Opt 2: Have 2 separate listeners - keyup for text fields and on-change for everything else. Opt 3: Add a flag when the event is fired and only call the ajax function if it's not been called already for that field. Personally, I'd remove the keyup listener else it will be making an ajax call for each key stroke.

Answer (score 0):

The point of having a datepicker is to avoid the need to manually type a date, because this has so many issues re date formats, validation, etc. So you shouldn't be using key events for them. In fact, consider using the readonly attribute on those inputs.

See `datepicker.onSelect()` to get the date as it is selected:

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect

In my opinion, the easiest way is to assemble all the data just before you do the AJAX call, instead of using events. In this case, you would use the `getDate()` function:

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate

Answer (score 0):

In addition to moob's answer, you could use jQuery's .change() event - a shortcut for .on( "change", handler )

https://api.jquery.com/change/